# Spring web security: unable to access a page after successful login

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to understand the spring-web security. For that I created a web application with a login page and two different users.

1. Admin
2. User/Guest

LoginController class handles three types of URLs.

```
/*
  Used to guide the user to login page
*/
@RequestMapping(value="/login/login.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView login(){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("login");
    System.out.println("Rendering login page.................");
    return modelAndView;
}

/*
 Process the successful login and redirects user to Admin/User page as per the role.
*/
@RequestMapping(value="/login/success")
public ModelAndView loginSuccess(HttpServletRequest request){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

     Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils
                .authorityListToSet(SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                        .getAuthentication().getAuthorities());
    System.out.println("ROLES: "+roles);

    if(roles.contains("USER_ADMIN")){
        modelAndView.setViewName("admin");
    }else{
        modelAndView.setViewName("user");
    }

    return modelAndView;
}

/* 
  Admin page has a hyper link to access the manage user page. It is handled here.
*/
@RequestMapping(value="/admin/manageUser.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView manageUser(){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("manageUser");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

**web.xml**

> ```
> <context-param>
>   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
>   <param-value>/WEB-INF/SecurityConfig.xml</param-value>
> </context-param>
>
> <listener>
>   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
> </listener>
>
>
> <servlet>
>   <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
>   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
>   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
> </servlet>
> <servlet-mapping>
>   <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
>   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
>
>
> <!-- Spring Security -->
> <filter>
>   <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
>   <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
> </filter>
>
> <filter-mapping>
>   <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
>   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
> </filter-mapping>
> ```

in spring security I am restricting all urls with '**admin/**' & '**user/**'.

> ```
> <http auto-config="true">
>     <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('USER_ADMIN')"/>
>     <intercept-url pattern="/user/**" access="hasRole('USER_GUEST')"/>
>     <form-login login-page="/login/login.htm" 
>         username-parameter="userName" password-parameter="password"
>         login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
>         authentication-success-forward-url="/login/success"/>
>
>     <remember-me/>
>
> </http>
>
> <authentication-manager>
>     <authentication-provider>
>         <user-service>
>             <user name="renju" password="12345" authorities="USER_ADMIN"/>
>             <user name="guest" password="guest"  authorities="USER_GUEST"/>
>         </user-service>
>     </authentication-provider>
> </authentication-manager>
> ```

When i try 'http://localhost:8080/SpringWebSecurityThree-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/login/login.htm', application opens up the custom login page.
[image]

On giving the admin username and password, application opens up the admin page.

[image]

Now when i click on 'ManageUser', I am expecting the application to take me tothe manageuser page. But it says 'Access Denied'.

[image]

I believe it has something to do with the intercept-url's given.

Could you please help me to resolve this?

I am posting jsp pages too..

**login.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <c:if test="${not empty error}">
        <c:out value="${error}"></c:out>
    </c:if>
    <form action="../j_spring_security_check" method="post">

        <table>

            <tr>
                <td>UserName</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="userName"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
            </tr>

                        <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="LOGIN"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
            value="${_csrf.token}" />


    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**admin.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@ page session="true" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    Admin Page !!!!!!!!!!
    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/manageUser.htm">ManageUser</a>
    <% session.setAttribute("userType", "admin"); %>
</body>
</html>
```

**manageuser.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page session="true" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    Managing User....
    <br/>
    Logged In UserType: 
    <%
        out.println(session.getAttribute("userType"));
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using create-session="never" which will required to do "re-authentication" for each of your request.

```
<http auto-config="true" create-session="never">
  <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('USER_ADMIN')"/>
  <intercept-url pattern="/user/**" access="hasRole('USER_GUEST')"/>
  <form-login login-page="/login/login.htm" 
     username-parameter="userName" password-parameter="password"
     login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
     authentication-success-forward-url="/login/success"/>

  <remember-me/>
</http>
```

This is generally used where cookie / session based authentications are not supported or implemented. Make sure to determine your strategy.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't kept it intentionally. I kept it while i was playing around with http tag to resolve this issue. Also tried 'create-session='always'. That also didn't worked. Removed it.

Comment: I do not have any error logs in JBoss console. I believe it is some condition that I kept in the security config is blocking it. So there is nothing to error out.

Comment: @Renju you are getting HTTP 403 it means your server don't have any issue with your authentication. You are authenticated already. But it failed on authorization instead. Your role is not seems to be "USER_ADMIN" as expected by the spring security configuration. Enable logging as DEBUG in your jboss and check if the role coming out to be as expected.